# admissibility of bayes rule

Tags: decision-theory

How to show that for a binomial(n, p) distribution, the MLE X/n is admissible under square error loss? 
The Bayes rule undr square error loss with beta($\alpha, \beta$) prior is X+$\alpha$/ (n +$\alpha + \beta)$.
Is there any way to show the two rules to be equivalent?

Comment: To which "two rules" are you referring? If you mean the two *estimators* given by $X/n$ and $(X+\alpha)/(n+\alpha+\beta)$, then--given they are obviously different whenever $\alpha\ne 0$ or $\beta \ne 0$--then what do you mean by "equivalent"?

Comment: What I mean is that if I can show that the risks are same for the two rules then I can say that X/n is admissible since if two bayes rules are unique upto equivalence they are admissible

Comment: The only way the Bayes $B(a,b)$ estimator of $p$ is useful is when constructing a sequence of proper Bayes estimators converging to the improper Bayes estimator. But it is not necessary here (see my answer).

Answer (score 4):

The connection between admissibility and Bayes is that a Bayes estimator with a finite Bayes risk is admissible. The MLE $X/n$ is the Bayes estimator for the improper prior $\pi(p)=1/p(1-p)$ and hence the Bayes risk is
\begin{align*}
r(\pi) &= \frac{1}{n^2}\,\int_0^1 \mathbb{E}_p[(X-np)^2] \pi(p)\text{d}p\\ 
&= \frac{1}{n^2}\,\int_0^1 np(1-p)\frac{1}{p(1-p)}\,\text{d}p\\
&= \frac{1}{n}
\end{align*}
Since it is finite, $X/n$ is admissible. (See [my book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387715983) for more details!)